# Mono "NetDataContractSerializer.Serialize"

Tags: mono, datacontractserializer

I'm getting following exception

```
System.NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented.
      at System.Runtime.Serialization.NetDataContractSerializer.WriteStartObject (System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter writer, System.Object graph) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject (System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter writer, System.Object graph) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject (System.Xml.XmlWriter writer, System.Object graph) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Runtime.Serialization.NetDataContractSerializer.Serialize (System.IO.Stream stream, System.Object graph) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at BinaryAnalysis.Data.ContractContainer.ContractContainerEntity.SetValue (System.Object val) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

When I try to serialize my Pono using NetDataContractSerializer using Mono 2.10.2-5.
There are no information about roadmap of theese classes in mono. 
Any workarounds for that?

Comment: You can write the needed classes yourself and contribute to Mono project, that's how Open Source grows. No other solution than that, I'm afraid. The code is on https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Runtime.Serialization/System.Runtime.Serialization/NetDataContractSerializer.cs and build instructions http://www.mono-project.com/Compiling_Mono_From_Git . I can assure you you'll learn a lot in the process!